# Button click event is not getting fired and Postback is false for the first time page loads, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am new to ASP.Net. I am using VS 2010 and targetting .net 4.0 framework. I am using ajaxtoolkit and my site is ajax enabled. I have a weird problem. I am not getting the button click event for a server button click for the first a few times. During this inside page_load, Postback property is false. The interesting thing is if navigate to any other page of my web site comes back and do the same thing, everything works fine(means I am getting button click event). I dont know what is happening wrong on first time.The other interesting thing is if I test from my machine(The computer where IIS is running), there is no issue. But the issue is very much producible from a browser in a different computer. I am just sitting without any clues. Can some one help me please?

My code is like below. I can not give the full source code, because of copyright issues. I am completely struck with this issue. Please help me

```
<%@ Page Title="TestPage" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MenuMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp"
    EnableEventValidation="false" 
 %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ControlContent">
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblProductGroup" runat="server" Text="ProductGroup></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbProductGroup" runat="server" Width="120px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text="Product"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbProduct" runat="server" Width="120px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSvcOptName" runat="server" Text="Option"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSvcOption" runat="server" Width="120px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue2">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDownForProductGroup" runat="server" TargetControlID="cmbProductGroup"
        Category="ProductGroup" LoadingText="[Loading ProductGroup...]" ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContentsBasedOnSelection" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDownForProduct" runat="server" TargetControlID="cmbProduct"
        Category="Product" LoadingText="[Loading Products...]" ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContentsBasedOnSelection"
        ParentControlID="cmbProductGroup" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDownForSvcOptions" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="cmbSvcOption" Category="Option" LoadingText="[Loading Options...]"
        ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContentsBasedOnSelection" ParentControlID="cmbProduct" />
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNumber" runat="server" Text="Serial Number"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialNumber" runat="server" Text="123456789" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValidator">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="serialNumReqFieldValidator" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter serial number" ControlToValidate="txtSerialNumber">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblExpiryDate" runat="server" Text="Expiry Date"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="expiryDateCalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtExpDate"
                PopupButtonID="calendarImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue2">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="calendarImage" runat="Server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png"
                AlternateText="Click to show calendar" />
        </div>
        <div class="controlValidator">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="expDateReqFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a date"  ControlToValidate="txtExpDate">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="expDateValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtExpDate"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date" OnServerValidate="expDateValidator_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CartUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="controlWrapper">
                <div class="controlLabel">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSelOptions" runat="server" Text="Options In Cart"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="controlValue1">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxSvcOptions" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:ListBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddToCart" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnClearCart" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="controlLabel">
            <asp:Label ID="lblGenKey" runat="server" Text="Generated Key"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlValue1">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtKeyGenerated" runat="server" Width="120px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="valSummary">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="valSummary">
            <asp:Label ID="lblOprStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlWrapper">
        <div class="ThreeButton">
            <asp:Button ID="btnGenKey" runat="server" Text="Generate Key"  OnClick="btnGenKey_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="ThreeButton">
            <asp:Button ID="btnGenKeyFile" runat="server" Text="Generate Key File" OnClick="btnGenKeyFile_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="ThreeButton">
            <asp:Button ID="btnClearCart" runat="server" Text="Clear Cart" OnClick="btnClearCart_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Any solutions yet? I think this might be caused by a validator that says the page is invalid.